# How to get specified values from ansbile facts

Tags: json, parsing, jinja2, ansible-facts, jmespath

I'm confused a little bit.
I alredy tried jmespath, but didn't help.
I need to get a high-level object which contains a specified object.
In the example below we see an ansible fact about HDDs. I need to get the disk name (`sdf`, `sdg` or `dm-0`) of the HDD which contains a specified partition, e.g. `sdf1`.

I've got this jmespath query:

```
msg.*.[partitions.sdf1]
```

but it just shows me all inside `sdf1`. Filters like `[?partitions=="sdf1"]` don't work here,
so the question is: how to preserve the whole `sdf` object in my example?

thanks in advance!

```
  {
    "msg": {
        "sdf": {
            "partitions": {
                "sdf1": {
                    "holders": [],
                    "links": {
                        "ids": [
                            "17101686F123-part1",
                            "wwn-0x123456-part1"
                        ]
                    },
                    "sectors": "1875380224"
                 }
            },
            "removable": "0",
            "rotational": "0"
        },
        "sdg": {
            "partitions": {
                "sdg1": {
                    "holders": [],
                    "links": {
                        "ids": [
                            "164414123CEB-part1",
                            "wwn-0x1233451234831ceb-part1"
                        ]
                    },
                     "uuid": "F301-FA7F"
                }
             },
            "removable": "0"
         },
        "dm-0": {
            "holders": [],
            "host": "",
            "links": {
                "ids": [],
                "uuids": []
            },
            "vendor": null,
            "virtual": 1
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
msg.*.{value: @, condition: partitions.sdf1}[?condition].value
```

#### explanation

At first we create a temporary object For each HDD object: `{value, condition}`. `condition` will be `null` if `partitions.sdf1` doesn't exist on the corresponding HDD (`sdf`, `sdg` `dm-0`) object. If `partitions.sdf1` exists, `condition` will contain that object, that is:

```
"condition": {
  "holders": [],
  "links": {
    "ids": [
      "17101686F123-part1",
      "wwn-0x123456-part1"
    ]
  },
  "sectors": "1875380224"
}
```

Using `[?condition]` you filter out all objects where `condition` is `null`. Finally, we extract the actual value using `.value`